# Bug in mat4x4_mul_quat in linmath.h?

Tags: opengl

Is there a bug in mat4x4_mul_quat in linmath.h (running Fedora 20, gcc gcc-4.8.3-7.fc20.i686) ?

If I multiply an identity matrix my an identify quaternion :

```
quat q1; quat_identity(q1);
mat4x4 m1; mat4x4_identity(m1);
mat4x4 r; mat4x4_mul_quat(r, m1, q1);
```

... I get :

```
{{0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}}
```

If I make my own mat4x4_mul_quat routine :

```
static inline void mat4x4_mul_quat0(mat4x4 R, mat4x4 M, quat q)
/// bug in mat4x4_mul_quat ??
{
    mat4x4 tmp0;
    mat4x4_from_quat(tmp0, q);
    mat4x4_mul(R, M, tmp0);
}
```

... it works fine.

Comment: I've never used it, but the [function definitions](https://github.com/datenwolf/linmath.h/blob/master/linmath.h) look weird: `static inline void mat4x4_mul_quat(mat4x4 R, mat4x4 M, quat q)
{
 quat_mul_vec3(R[0], M[0], q);` and further down below: `static inline void quat_mul_vec3(vec3 r, quat q, vec3 v)`. Note the quaternion is passed as third parameter but expected as second. Perhaps I'm blind.

Comment: @StefanHanke: Yes, that's definitely the wrong ordering there. Will fix it.

Answer (score 1):

As the author of linmath.h I ask you please open an new issue about that. I repeatedly remind people, that much of the code has been written in-situ and may contain bugs in several places.

I have to look into the issue and the quaternion code definitely may contain some bugs; mich of the quaternion code has been written in the dawn hours of the day, and when it worked for a certain experiment I commited it ;), the fun thing about this quaternion multiplication there is, that in the use case I wrote it for the ordering of those two actually didn't matter. That's why I didn't notice it.

Submission of test cases highly appreciated.

#### Update 1:

Another issue with that function is, that it actually implements the case

```
M' = q · M
```

and not what one would assume (`M' = M · q`); fixing this is rather straightforward though: Swapping the order of matrices in matrix-matrix multiplications needs the matrices to be transposed. In the case of a quaternions this corresponds to the transpose of the corresponding matrix, but since matrices derived from quaternions are always orthogonal, the transpose is the inverse, which means, the inverse quaternion has to be applied which is the conjugate. Also the w-column of the matrix is not yet respected. I'll have to fix that ASAP.

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks for the code, BTW.  I know there is GLM & Eigen, but those are C++, and I prefer C at this point. I wrote some additional functions : quat_rotate , quat_pre_rotate .